# Not hitting a function when posting a route in testing

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a feature test and I'm trying to post to a route, but I'm not hitting that route and what I mean by that
is, when I `dd()` in that function that I need to get into, I'm not getting the output from the `dd()` that lets me know that I've hit my function.

Here is my test function

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

class CategoryTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => 'Test User',
            'email' => 'test@test.com'
            'password' => bcrypt('password')
        ]);

        $this->actingAs($user, 'web');
    }
    private function createTestCategory()
    {
        $category = Category::create([
            'name' => 'Category 1'
        ]);

        return $category;
    }

    public function testCategoryVersion()
    {
        $category = $this->createTestCategory();

        $version = [
            'version' => 'v1'
        ];

        $response = $this->call('POST', "/api/project/{$category->id}/version", [
            'version' => $version
        ]);

        dd($response);
    }
}
```

and this is what I get in return

```
Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse^ {#12704
  +baseResponse: Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse^ {#13339
    #request: Illuminate\Http\Request^ {#13504
      #json: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag^ {#14972
        #parameters: array:1 [
          "version" => array:1 [
            "version" => "v1"
          ]
        ]
      }
      #convertedFiles: null
      #userResolver: Closure($guard = null)^ {#14453
        class: "Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider"
        this: Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider {#16961 …}
        use: {
          $app: Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#17080 …}
        }
        file: "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php"
        line: "105 to 107"
      }
      #routeResolver: Closure()^ {#15018
        class: "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
        this: Illuminate\Routing\Router {#16256 …}
        use: {
          $route: Illuminate\Routing\Route {#14382 …}
        }
        file: "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
        line: "655 to 657"
      }
      +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag^ {#12703
        #parameters: []
      }
      +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag^ {#14972}
      +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag^ {#11883
        #parameters: []
      }
      +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag^ {#14949
        #parameters: array:19 [
          "SERVER_NAME" => "localhost"
          "SERVER_PORT" => 80
          "HTTP_HOST" => "localhost"
          "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Symfony"
          "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "application/json"
          "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-us,en;q=0.5"
          "HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET" => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
          "REMOTE_ADDR" => "127.0.0.1"
          "SCRIPT_NAME" => ""
          "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => ""
          "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
          "REQUEST_TIME" => 1644936692
          "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1644936692.2835
          "HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" => 28
          "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/json"
          "PATH_INFO" => ""
          "REQUEST_METHOD" => "POST"
          "REQUEST_URI" => "/api/project/1/version"
          "QUERY_STRING" => ""
        ]
      }
      +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag^ {#14964
        #parameters: []
      }
      +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag^ {#16109
        #parameters: []
      }
      +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag^ {#11625
        #headers: array:8 [
          "host" => array:1 [
            0 => "localhost"
          ]
          "user-agent" => array:1 [
            0 => "Symfony"
          ]
          "accept" => array:1 [
            0 => "application/json"
          ]
          "accept-language" => array:1 [
            0 => "en-us,en;q=0.5"
          ]
          "accept-charset" => array:1 [
            0 => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
          ]
          "content-length" => array:1 [
            0 => 28
          ]
          "content-type" => array:1 [
            0 => "application/json"
          ]
          "origin" => array:1 [
            0 => ""
          ]
        ]
        #cacheControl: []
      }
      #content: "{"version":{"version":"v1"}}"
      #languages: null
      #charsets: null
      #encodings: null
      #acceptableContentTypes: array:1 [
        0 => "application/json"
      ]
      #pathInfo: "/api/project/1/version"
      #requestUri: "/api/project/1/version"
      #baseUrl: ""
      #basePath: null
      #method: "POST"
      #format: null
      #session: null
      #locale: null
      #defaultLocale: "en"
      -preferredFormat: null
      -isHostValid: true
      -isForwardedValid: true
      -isSafeContentPreferred: null
      basePath: ""
      format: "html"
    }
    #session: Illuminate\Session\Store^ {#11680
      #id: "sGsZ8cj5iRPLBjfLT4quiaal9LjdOEJUakzno0CU"
      #name: "laravel_session"
      #attributes: array:2 [
        "error" => "Your account has been disabled. Please contact us at <a href="mailto:test@test.com">test@test.com</a>"
        "_flash" => array:2 [
          "new" => array:1 [
            0 => "error"
          ]
          "old" => []
        ]
      ]
      #handler: Illuminate\Session\ArraySessionHandler^ {#11912
        #storage: []
        #minutes: "120"
      }
      #started: false
    }
    #targetUrl: "http://localhost/login"
    +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag^ {#14761
      #computedCacheControl: array:2 [
        "no-cache" => true
        "private" => true
      ]
      #cookies: []
      #headerNames: array:5 [
        "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
        "date" => "Date"
        "location" => "Location"
        "content-type" => "Content-Type"
        "access-control-allow-origin" => "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
      ]
      #headers: array:5 [
        "cache-control" => array:1 [
          0 => "no-cache, private"
        ]
        "date" => array:1 [
          0 => "Tue, 15 Feb 2022 14:51:32 GMT"
        ]
        "location" => array:1 [
          0 => "http://localhost/login"
        ]
        "content-type" => array:1 [
          0 => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        ]
        "access-control-allow-origin" => array:1 [
          0 => ""
        ]
      ]
      #cacheControl: []
    }
    #content: """
      <!DOCTYPE html>\n
      <html>\n
          <head>\n
              <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n
              <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://localhost/login'" />\n
      \n
              <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/login</title>\n
          </head>\n
          <body>\n
              Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/login">http://localhost/login</a>.\n
          </body>\n
      </html>
      """
    #version: "1.1"
    #statusCode: 302
    #statusText: "Found"
    #charset: null
    +original: null
    +exception: null
  }
  #streamedContent: null
}
```

Comment: Try adding `use Tests\TestCase;` below the `namespace` declaration.

Comment: Looking at your error it seems it is redirecting to login page. Suggest using `actingAs` method in your test post request. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#session-and-authentication